# Android Parse Google Places API JSON

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

I'm trying to take the information from the JSON returned by Google Places.

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {  
    JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(result.getString("name"));

    if (result.getJSONArray("reviews") != null){
         JSONArray reviewsArray = result.getJSONArray("reviews");
         JSONObject reviews = reviewsArray.getJSONObject(0);
         if (reviews != null){
              String review = reviews.getString("text");  
              Log.d("tag", "review: " + review);
         }  
    }

}
```

My question is, how can I make sure the either "name" or "reviews" are available to parse? that `if (result.getJSONArray("reviews") != null)` still fails because getJSONArray is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the opt commands instead of the get commands. Change the get json array to the following:

```
(result.optJSONArray("reviews") != null)
```

Check out the [JSONObject documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) for a complete list. You can also use the JSONObject [has(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) command to check if it exists before actually getting it.

Comment: hey man, so I'm still not getting anything for reviews.  When I check the JSON that's returned, I don't even see the "reviews" array.  but I check the google maps for the same place and I can see that there are a few reviews.  Any idea why it wouldn't include that?

Comment: @MoMoney You should probably create a new question and post the api call you are making with the json that is returned. You can link to the new question here.

Comment: here you go.  any help will be much appreciated. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924703/android-google-places-api-no-reviews-array)

Answer (score 0):

Since your json is initially in the form of a [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html), you could use it's `isNull(String name)` helper method to check if a mapping exists and isn't null.

From the documentation:

> isNull(String name) Returns true if this object has no mapping for
>   name or if it has a mapping whose value is NULL.

For example:

```
try {

jsonObj = new JSONObject(data);
if(!jsonObj.isNull("results")){
  JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");

  for (int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++) {  
      JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
      if(!result.isNull("name"){
          System.out.println(result.getString("name"));
      }

      if (result.getJSONArray("reviews") != null){
           JSONArray reviewsArray = result.getJSONArray("reviews");
           JSONObject reviews = reviewsArray.getJSONObject(0);
           if (reviews != null){
                String review = reviews.getString("text");  
                Log.d("tag", "review: " + review);
           }  
        }
     }
  }
} catch(JSONException e){
     //Something went wrong
}
```