# Android - Google Places API - No "reviews" Array

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

So I'm running the following Google Places API call:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=34.0467359,-118.441764&rankby=distance&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY&types=restaurant`

part of my JSON output is:

```
"results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 34.047332,
           "lng" : -118.443431
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
     "id" : "03ed19ca32b20080897e31095e6eed2715cde819",
     "name" : "Del Taco",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true
     },
     "price_level" : 1,
     "reference" : "CnRrAAAA6Dqit_GeW6rLNFXGo4cb-SBPdIr09vVlvU7n2W8QVesy6svOTDQu-lkhbdWPBPM64uR3a8pwer_dwbwi1weyKXIhTYAa0deSu4-Xp3S8K2LvPexGFCd7oasJ1dK8ZtCAA4IvwQbpkM6GaJ9xCn1jqRIQ63-ofgMIddQpjtHoJcOlVhoUDwWYwlyV3hyVg-4jYExfcPPxhU4",
     "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "11066 Santa Monica Blvd, Los Angeles"
  },
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 34.047475,
           "lng" : -118.443474
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
     "id" : "6e6ae3ea79f06eb6c790ed533a35d9b3abc6c344",
     "name" : "Moon House Chinese Cuisine",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : true
     },
     "price_level" : 1,
     "reference" : "CoQBfAAAAFmSc3ErmitzFoxmNvuNXG5x0iJCWpXITFr9VtKcA5SRpcSyXmFW9LR_F2vLVUC4dCCSo7xQm_l_JaOuAttZmYJDonYNnobGAT6fVXR1Gw_p3lmJWwKgd7zTqeMCGXPk8kBT6ztYWzLpTEnKtg2u9jFRvYUerdBsv1Keso3yXVESEhBGizJBrGPMBDz2nte3wF81GhQ21SBkMNMSG6Bx0Ymi65rr2jyQBg",
     "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "11058 Santa Monica Blvd, Los Angeles"
  },
```

I check the JSON that's returned, I don't even see the "reviews" array. but I check the google maps for the same place and I can see that there are a few reviews. Any idea why it wouldn't include that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allright the problem is that place API doesen't include reviews. But if u want to get reviews then u have to make place detail request.

eg: this is sample place request

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?
location=34.0467359,-118.441764&radius=1000&sensor=true
&key=YOUR_PLACE_API_KEY&types=restaurant
```

this is sample place details request

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?
reference=REFERENCE_STRING_OF_THE_PLACE&sensor=true&key=YOUR_PLACE_API_KEY
```

Comment: This is correct. If you want reviews you will need to make both calls. Make the search call to find locations and make the details call for each location you would like reviews for.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `search` use `near by search` as follows:-

and also include radius :

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=34.0467359,-118.441764&radius=50000&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY&types=restaurant
```

Comment: that didn't make any difference.  i've tried that before.  not sure what the difference really is but either way it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get review array by place detail API

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid={place_id}&key={api_key}

where place id is results id field from your response,

Ex. "id" : "03ed19ca32b20080897e31095e6eed2715cde819",