# Android Java Google Places GET (Pull) Reviews JSONException No value for reviews

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, google-places-api, review

I checked and made sure google places api for android was enabled.

At first I was using this url:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=34.0467359,-118.441764&radius=1000&sensor=true&key=YOUR_PLACE_API_KEY
```

and switched to this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json? reference=REFERENCE_STRING_OF_THE_PLACE&sensor=true&key=YOUR_PLACE_API_KEY
```

as per recommendation in

[Android - Google Places API - No "reviews" Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924703/android-google-places-api-no-reviews-array/39614639#39614639)

but still got the same error.

On https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

It was stated that reference was deprecated and now we have to use place_id. I changed the url to:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Later on I read on stackoverflow  that in 2012 google places API did not have the functionality to pull reviews. Is this applicable to now? In 2016? If not, please help me decipher in my code below what I did (am doing) wrong.

If I copy and paste any of the log outputs for any of the above urls, the reviews are showing in my browser but the output in the response is not displaying the url.

I am getting this error:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for reviews 

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389) 

W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)

W/System.err:    at DownloadReviewsTask.doInBackground(DownloadReviewsTask.java:69)

W/System.err:     at DownloadReviewsTask.doInBackground(DownloadReviewsTask.java:19)

W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)

W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)

W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)  

W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 

W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 

W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is my code below:

```
public class JSONParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;

    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      HashMap<String, String> params) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setReadTimeout(90000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(90000);

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(90000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

```js
public class DownloadReviewsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, HashMap<String, List<MyModel>>> {
    //Declarations
    private Context mContext;
    public Exception mException;
    private OnEventListener<HashMap<String, List<MyModel>>> mCallBack;
    JSONArray reviews;
    String author_name;
    String text;
    //Constructor
    public DownloadReviewsTask(Context context, OnEventListener callback) {
        mCallBack = callback;
        mContext = context;
    }
    //sets and passes the review author and text for each review and sets them in the My Model
    public MyModel setPlace(JSONObject thisObject) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject results = thisObject.getJSONObject("results");
       MyModel thisMyModel = new MyModel();
        if (!results.isNull("reviews")) {
            reviews = results.getJSONArray("reviews");
            Log.e("reviews array setPlace", String.valueOf(reviews));
            for (int i = 0; i < reviews.length(); i++) {
                //if(i==reviews.length()) break;
               // if (thisObject.getJSONArray("reviews").getJSONObject(i).has("author_name")) //{
                    author_name = results.getJSONArray("reviews").getJSONObject(i).getString("author_name");//reviews.getJSONObject(i).getString("author");
                    Log.e("review_author in setup", results.getJSONArray("reviews").getJSONObject(i).getString("author_name"));
               // }
                //if (thisObject.getJSONArray("reviews").getJSONObject(i).has("text")) {
                    Log.e("review text in setup", results.getJSONArray("reviews").getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
                    text = results.getJSONArray("reviews").getJSONObject(i).getString("text");//}

                thisMyModel.setAuthor_name(author_name);
                thisMyModel.setText(text);
            }
        }
        return thisMyModel;
    }

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, List<MyModel>> doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json;
            String reviewUrl = args[0];
            Log.e("reviewUrl",reviewUrl);
            //Use a HashMap instead with the varargs:
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(reviewUrl, "GET", params);
            HashMap<String, List<MyModel>> myResults = new HashMap<>();
            if(json != null) {
                Log.e("reviews result", json.toString());
                JSONArray parentArray = json.getJSONArray("reviews");
                List<MyModel> allEventsList = new ArrayList<>();
                //loops through json array
                for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    allEventsList.add(setPlace(finalObject));
                    Log.e("allEventsList", String.valueOf(allEventsList));
                }
                myResults.put("reviews", allEventsList);
                Log.e("myResults",String.valueOf(myResults));
                return myResults;

            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, List<MyModel>> result) {
        if (mCallBack != null) {
            if (mException == null) {
                mCallBack.onSuccess(result);
            } else {
                mCallBack.onFailure(mException);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class MyModel{
        private String reference;
        public void setReference(String reference) {
            this.reference = reference;
        }
        public String getReference() {
            return reference;
        }
    }
```

```
public class MainActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              String reviewsUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference="+reference+sensor+key;
                  DownloadReviewsTask rev = new DownloadReviewsTask(this, new OnEventListener<HashMap<String, List<MyModel>>>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(HashMap<String, List<MyModel>> result) {
                    if(result != null && result.size() > 0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
                            Log.e("review SingleVewInit",result.get("reviews").get(0).getAuthor_name());
                            Log.e("review SingleVewInit",result.get("reviews").get(0).getText());
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("ERROR: " ,e.getMessage());
                }
            });
            rev.execute(reviewsUrl);
  }

}
```

Comment: I think that you are able only to GET reviews and still not possibility to submit them. Because in this case, everybody could send reviews automatically and reviews will lost their seriousness

Comment: @Hrabosch The code is to pull (GET) reviews and not to post reviews. By displaying in android app I mean just put the pulled review in a textView. The above code does not generate reviews. They already exist on google

Comment: @Hrabosch if you do have android java code that you feel does the job i.e. GET the reviews from google pretty well, please feel free to post it in an answer. Maybe I am wrong

Comment: @Hrabosch are you saying you went through my code and found out that it generates reviews instead? If so please help me see which lines those are

Comment: @JqueryNinja: I was able to fetch review array with below url - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: @JqueryNinja So sorry! I dont understand at first look. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright below is the sample code to fetch reviews. You need to understand the code and make necessary changes to work in your code.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=AIzaSyAAkK3AyE8Cbqb9H5MYqptjJwRhRgltoZM");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

                int ch = -1;
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while((ch = in.read()) != -1){
                    buffer.append((char)ch);
                }

                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
                JSONObject jResult = jObj.getJSONObject("result");
                JSONArray jReviewArray = jResult.getJSONArray("reviews");

                for(int i=0; i<jReviewArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jReview = jReviewArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    System.out.println( jReview.getString("author_name") +"\n"+ jReview.getString("text") +"\n\n");
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

It prints the Author_Name with Review_Text.

Update your code as below-

1. In **DownloadReviewsTask**-

change `JSONArray parentArray = json.getJSONArray("reviews");`

to     `JSONArray parentArray = json.getJSONArray("result");`

2. change **setPlace()** as below-

   ```
   public MyModel setPlace(JSONObject thisObject) throws JSONException {

   MyModel thisMyModel = new MyModel();
   author_name = thisObject.getString("author_name");
   text = thisObject.getString("text");

   thisMyModel.setAuthor_name(author_name);
   thisMyModel.setText(text);

   return thisMyModel;

   }
   ```
3. I didn't found **setAuthor_name()** and **setText()** methods inside **MyModal** so change it as below-

   ```
   public class MyModel{
   private String reference;
   private String author_name;
   private String text;

   public void setAuthor_name(String author_name) {
       this.author_name = author_name;
   }
   public String getAuthor_name() {
       return author_name;
   }

   public void setText(String text) {
       this.text = text;
   }
   public String getText() {
       return text;
   }

   public void setReference(String reference) {
       this.reference = reference;
   }
   public String getReference() {
       return reference;
   }
   }
   ```
4. finally change the Log stmt as in **MainActivity** as below-

   ```
   Log.e("review SingleVewInit",result.get(i).getAuthor_name());
   Log.e("review SingleVewInit",result.get(i).getText());
   ```

Comment: So I put this in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: Could I please have the complete code for the class. I have never used threads before.

Answer (score 0):

@kevz

I think your original answer was good enough. There is no need for an Async Task. I created a small project just to test your ideas, and it worked!!! Trying to combine them with my code results in a mess. Please see below, just in case it helps anyone:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Places">
    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_author"
        android:id="@+id/button_id"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and below, should be enough:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Places extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_places);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {

                            URL url = new java.net.URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=AIzaSyAAkK3AyE8Cbqb9H5MYqptjJwRhRgltoZM");
                            //HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            InputStream in = url.openStream();

                            int ch = -1;
                            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                            while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
                                buffer.append((char) ch);
                            }

                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
                            JSONObject jResult = jObj.getJSONObject("result");
                            JSONArray jReviewArray = jResult.getJSONArray("reviews");
                            //Float rating = (float)jResult.getDouble("rating");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jReviewArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jReview = jReviewArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.e("review",jReview.getString("author_name") + "\n" + jReview.getString("text") + "\n\n");
                                Log.e("rating", jResult.getString("rating") + "\n");
                            }

                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Justine OBRIEN
                                                                          Fabulous location. Wonderful warm welcoming reception. Excellent unique living Google wall entry. Sensational helpful kind people. Easy fast efficient help online plus with appointment on site. Super company always progressive plus innovative products and services for all businesses. Go Google Australia. Shine on! 
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: James Pallett
                                                                          I can not understand why Google would choose Titan Digital as one their 14 Premier Partners. It was on this basis that I choose Titan to build my new web site. It is costing me dearly. All words, no action, over promise, under deliver. My second biggest complaint, of many, about Titan, after the total mismanagement of my project, is Titan's lack of communication. Days and weeks go by without a word. Inquiries are either ignored or treated with indifference. Almost eight months have passed since I signed up for a new web site and inquiries receive no urgency, only platitudes. To add insult to injury, Titan has the audacity to charge for monthly web maintenance for a web site still long overdue in production. Be warned.
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: Dorothy Ooko
                                                                          Cool offices.... Reception on the 5th floor. Best coffee barrista is on the 4thð
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: Taylor Hayes
                                                                          Absolute joke trying to find who to deal with in regards to services i have paid for. Happy to take the money and told its all easy . . . .weeks i have waited to finish verifying my coffee shop after purchasing a virtual tour pathetic aftercare
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: TheHealthRetreat
                                                                          I spend 250 thousand dollars a year with Google adwords..
                                                                          I own a Mental Health Drug and alcohol retreat.
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: Justine OBRIEN
                                                                          Fabulous location. Wonderful warm welcoming reception. Excellent unique living Google wall entry. Sensational helpful kind people. Easy fast efficient help online plus with appointment on site. Super company always progressive plus innovative products and services for all businesses. Go Google Australia. Shine on! 
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: James Pallett
                                                                          I can not understand why Google would choose Titan Digital as one their 14 Premier Partners. It was on this basis that I choose Titan to build my new web site. It is costing me dearly. All words, no action, over promise, under deliver. My second biggest complaint, of many, about Titan, after the total mismanagement of my project, is Titan's lack of communication. Days and weeks go by without a word. Inquiries are either ignored or treated with indifference. Almost eight months have passed since I signed up for a new web site and inquiries receive no urgency, only platitudes. To add insult to injury, Titan has the audacity to charge for monthly web maintenance for a web site still long overdue in production. Be warned.
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: Dorothy Ooko
                                                                          Cool offices.... Reception on the 5th floor. Best coffee barrista is on the 4thð
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: Taylor Hayes
                                                                          Absolute joke trying to find who to deal with in regards to services i have paid for. Happy to take the money and told its all easy . . . .weeks i have waited to finish verifying my coffee shop after purchasing a virtual tour pathetic aftercare
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: TheHealthRetreat
                                                                          I spend 250 thousand dollars a year with Google adwords..
                                                                          I own a Mental Health Drug and alcohol retreat.
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: Justine OBRIEN
                                                                          Fabulous location. Wonderful warm welcoming reception. Excellent unique living Google wall entry. Sensational helpful kind people. Easy fast efficient help online plus with appointment on site. Super company always progressive plus innovative products and services for all businesses. Go Google Australia. Shine on! 
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: James Pallett
                                                                          I can not understand why Google would choose Titan Digital as one their 14 Premier Partners. It was on this basis that I choose Titan to build my new web site. It is costing me dearly. All words, no action, over promise, under deliver. My second biggest complaint, of many, about Titan, after the total mismanagement of my project, is Titan's lack of communication. Days and weeks go by without a word. Inquiries are either ignored or treated with indifference. Almost eight months have passed since I signed up for a new web site and inquiries receive no urgency, only platitudes. To add insult to injury, Titan has the audacity to charge for monthly web maintenance for a web site still long overdue in production. Be warned.
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: Dorothy Ooko
                                                                          Cool offices.... Reception on the 5th floor. Best coffee barrista is on the 4thð
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: Taylor Hayes
                                                                          Absolute joke trying to find who to deal with in regards to services i have paid for. Happy to take the money and told its all easy . . . .weeks i have waited to finish verifying my coffee shop after purchasing a virtual tour pathetic aftercare
 E/rating: 4.6
 E/review: TheHealthRetreat
                                                                          I spend 250 thousand dollars a year with Google adwords..
                                                                          I own a Mental Health Drug and alcohol retreat.
E/rating: 4.6
```

Comment: glad u were able to figure it out and did managed to change  ur code into much simple code :)